# Mappings and usage of Kotlin data types and Swift data types

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Let's say I have a function *foo* which takes two arguments:

```
actual fun foo(list1: List<Long>, list2: List<Double>) {
...
}
```

According to the https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/apple-framework.html Kotlin's Long type is mapped to `KotlinLong` and Kotlin's Double is mapped to `KotlinDouble`. Now I would like to call this function from my iOS App. Let's say I have two arrays:

```
let list1Numbers = [1000.43, 564121.34, 5617172172.234, 100.7]
let list2Numbers = [2.1, 3.2, 1.7]
```

For the `list2` I could do something like:

```
let list2NumbersKotlin = list2Numbers.map({KotlinDouble.init(double: $0)})
```

which is not very convenient but will work. The `list1` is a bit more problematic. Since there is no `Long` in Swift, I do something like

```
let list1NumbersKotlin =  list1Numbers.map({KotlinLong.init(longLong: Int64($0))})
```

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to do it ?
2. What is a typical approach to deal with such types mapping when using Kotlin as an iOS Framework ? Unfortunately I couldn't find any examples on the Internet.
3. Should certain types such as Long be completely avoided if I want to use Kotlin as iOS Framework ?
4. Also, regarding mapping in general: since the Kotlin function

   ```
    fun testDouble(testVal: Double) {}
   ```

allows me to pass in Swift the Double directly:

```
HelloKt.testDouble(testVal: Double)
```

then why does the function

```
fun testList(testList: List<Double>) {}
```

not allow me to enter Double array but requires a KotlinDouble array ?

```
HelloKt.testList(testList: [KotlinDouble]){}
```

Passing a [Double] gives error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Double]' to expected argument type
> '[KotlinDouble]'

Answer (score 4):

1. There are multiple ways.

You are talking about collections of data that are on the line between primitive types and objects, which tends to be a special case in Kotlin anyway.

Speaking to that, in Kotlin, you might want a `LongArray` and a `DoubleArray` rather than `List<Long>` and `List<Double>`. Coming from Swift, you'll be forced to explicitly box them. Kotlin will handle that for you when you're writing Kotlin code, but they're still getting boxed under the hood.

So, summary, either what you've done above, or take `LongArray` and `DoubleArray` as args rather than lists, and do a different translation. Either way, you will need to move the data into something Koltin compatible.

Obviously, if you put that in a helper function, ugly as it perhaps may be, you only need to do it once.

2. Either your method or what I described.
3. `Long` isn't problematic. There is a "long" in Swift, it's `Int64`. Having to wrap values like that isn't fun, but Kotlin and Swift are different languages, and there are compromises. If you use `Int` in Kotlin instead of `Long`, you'll need to wrap a Swift `Int` with `Int32`. A Kotlin `Int` is, in that sense, "problematic" in the same way. You need to specify which precision int you're using.
4. In Kotlin, `List<Long>` is a list of `Long` objects, while just a `Long` is a primitive value. Kotlin hides the boxing of those values, but they are boxed. The Swift/Kotlin interface is forcing you to be more explicit. If you want primitive values, use the ___Array forms mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to use ___Array forms with my existing Swift Double array by iterating over the Swift Double array and adding all elements with an index cast to Int32 to a new array. I noticed that there is also an option to pass the init function (KotlinInt)->(KotlinDouble) but I am unsure how it should look like. Do you know any code samples or references to the usage of Kotlin collections in Swift ? I spent a lot of time searching but 0 results.

Comment: Also: how can I efficiently deal with bigger amount of data ? Mapping an array which has 30 elements is not a problem but I have arrays which consist of thousands of elements and the whole process takes significant amount of time.